# Put hash map value arrayincorrect

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I had put value json array to hash map but just last value is correct. I still not clear with use hash map, list, and array list. my code:

```
Map<String, Object> departmentPHSSuportEmail = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> subSourceMap = null;

List<Map<String , Object>> myMap  = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

subSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
subSourceMap.put("name", "bobby");
subSourceMap.put("address", "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id");

subSourceMap.put("name", "2sadasd");
subSourceMap.put("address", "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id");      

subSourceMap.put("name", "ggfgf");
subSourceMap.put("address", "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id");      

myMap.add(0, subSourceMap);
myMap.add(1, subSourceMap);
myMap.add(2, subSourceMap);


Map<String, Object> attachment = new HashMap<String, Object>();
attachment.put(ApplicationConstanta.MsExchange.TYPE, "");
attachment.put(ApplicationConstanta.MsExchange.VALUE, "");
departmentPHSSuportEmail.put(ApplicationConstanta.EmailForwardString.ATTACHMENT, attachment);

Map<String, Object> subSource = new HashMap<String, Object>();
subSource.put(ApplicationConstanta.MsExchange.TYPE, ApplicationConstanta.MsExchange.STRING);
subSource.put(ApplicationConstanta.MsExchange.VALUE, myMap);
departmentPHSSuportEmail.put(ApplicationConstanta.EmailForwardString.SUB_SOURCE, subSource);

System.out.println("JSON : " + JsonUtil.toJson(departmentPHSSuportEmail));
```

result:

```
JSON : {
  "Attachment" : {
    "type" : "",
    "value" : ""
  },
  "SubSource" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "value" : [ {
      "address" : "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id",
      "name" : "ggfgf"
    }, {
      "address" : "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id",
      "name" : "ggfgf"
    }, {
      "address" : "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id",
      "name" : "ggfgf"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Why the value in "value" object all same? I had put the different value. how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: You're adding `subSourceMap` three times into `myMap`. If you want to add three different maps, you need to add three different maps, not one map three times.

Comment: If you're not familiar with how hashmaps, lists etc. work then you should concentrate on that instead of messing with json too. `subSourceMap.put("name", whatever);` will overwrite any value you put for the key `"name"` before. That means that `subSourceMap` will only contain the last values and adding the _same_ map 3 times to the list will just result in that: a list with 3 elements that are exactly the same (and when you change the content of one you change all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this problem because you re-use the same Hashmap object which basically overwrites your data.  Let's go through this step-by-step:

```
List<Map<String , Object>> myMap  = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

subSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
subSourceMap.put("name", "bobby");
subSourceMap.put("address", "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id");
```

Now your `subSourceMap` contains:

```
name: bobby
address: xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id
```

Then you do

```
subSourceMap.put("name", "2sadasd");
subSourceMap.put("address", "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id");
```

With this code you modify the existing `subSourceMap` and overwriting it's contents. Now your `subSourceMap` contains:

```
name: 2sadasd
address: xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id
```

Then you do:

```
subSourceMap.put("name", "ggfgf");
subSourceMap.put("address", "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id");
```

You are again modifying the existing `subSourceMap`.   Now your `subSourceMap` contains:

```
name: ggfgf
address: xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id
```

Finally you do:

```
myMap.add(0, subSourceMap);
myMap.add(1, subSourceMap);
myMap.add(2, subSourceMap);
```

This puts three references to the same `subSourceMap` into the list. It will not copy the map it just adds a reference to the same object in there. So when you now convert this list to JSON you will naturally see what you saw.

To fix this, you need to create a fresh map for each entry:

```
List<Map<String , Object>> myMap  = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

// create a fresh map
Map<String,Object> subSourceMap1 = new HashMap<>();
subSourceMap1.put("name", "bobby");
subSourceMap1.put("address", "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id");

// create a fresh map
Map<String,Object> subSourceMap2 = new HashMap<>();
subSourceMap2.put("name", "2sadasd");
subSourceMap2.put("address", "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id");      

// create a fresh map
Map<String,Object> subSourceMap3 = new HashMap<>();
subSourceMap3.put("name", "ggfgf");
subSourceMap3.put("address", "xxx.xxxx@xxx.co.id");      

// note that you do not need to specify the index here, just use
// add with 1 parameter which will append to the end of the list
myMap.add(subSourceMap1);
myMap.add(subSourceMap2);
myMap.add(subSourceMap3);
```

You can read this article about Java references which shows a similar example to get more familiar with how object references in Java work: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174371&seqNum=4